# Программа которое заменяет слово в строке

Tags: c, строки

нужно написать такую программу: Пользователь должен ввести предложение, слово которое хочет заменить в предложении, и слово которое каким он хочет заменить. Вышло что то подобное, может кто то подскажет, что и где нужно исправить

```
    #define SIZE 80

void newsentence(char a[], char b[], char c[], int n, int k);
void array(int f, int s, int g, char buff[], char b[], char c[], int n, int k);

int main()
{
    char a[SIZE], b[SIZE], c[SIZE];
    int k;

    printf("Enter the sentence: ");
    gets(a);
    printf("\nEnter the word which u want to replace: ");
    scanf("%s",b);
    printf("\nEnter the new word: ");
    scanf("%s",c);

    int n =0;
    char *temp;
    temp =a;

    while((temp =strstr(temp,b))!= NULL){
        n++;
        temp++;
        k = strstr(temp,b)-b;
    }
    printf("The word appears %d times",n);

    newsentence(a,b,c,n,k);
}

void newsentence(char a[], char b[], char c[], int n, int k)
{
    int f, s, g;
    char buff;

    f=strlen(a);
    s=strlen(b);
    g=strlen(c);

    strcpy(buff,a);

    array(f,s,g, buff,b,c,n,k);
}
void array(int f, int s, int g, char buff[], char b[], char c[], int n, int k)
{
    int i,j;
    int q;
    q = k +s - 1;

    for(j = 0; k<=q ;k++, j++)
    {
        if(strcmp(buff[k],b[j])==0){
            strcmp(buff[k],c[i]);
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i<SIZE;i++){
        printf("Yout new string is: %c",buff[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.

Comment: _что и где нужно исправить_ - какой у вас компилятор? Лучше всего начать с устранения замечаний, выдаваемых компилятором. `the 'gets' function is dangerous and should not be used` и т.д.

Comment: "*слово которое каким он хочет заменить*" - кто на ком стоял?

Comment: я изменил программу, надеюсь, так будет понятнее

Comment: Так а что не так с этой программой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, я тут набросал на коленке...

```
char * replace(const char* src, const char* old, const char* new)
{
    // Ищем количество вхождений old в src
    int count = 0;
    const char * c = src;
    while((c = strstr(c,old)) != NULL)
    {
        ++count;
        ++c;
    }
    // Вычисляем новую длину предложения
    int len = strlen(src) + count*(strlen(new) - strlen(old)) + 1;
    // Выделяем память
    char * s = malloc(len);
    // Указатели на старую строку
    const char * b = src;
    c = src;
    // На новую строку (текущее место копирования)
    char * e = s;
    while((c = strstr(c,old)) != NULL)
    {
        // Копируем кусок строки до старого слова
        memcpy(e,b,c-b);
        // и новое слово
        memcpy(e+(c-b),new,strlen(new));
        e += (c-b) + strlen(new);
        b = c + strlen(old);
        c = b;
    }
    strcpy(e,b);
    return s;
}
```

Смотрите, разбирайтесь...